# Difference between summation and integration

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I understand calculus and maths but when i apply statistics and add up numbers they both look kinda same

Can anybody explain the difference in a little detail and simple manner please

Comment: Please add more details. Why do they look the same for you? Can you supply an example?

Comment: I am learning statistics...Integration of f(x) and summation of f(x) are performed in the same way... By adding the values together... So i got confused and i realised until you don't have infitesimals in the equation they both look identical... Just give me a practical difference please.. It would be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most simple words-

> **Summation**- Sum of a *small numbers* of *large quantities*.
>
> **Integration**- Sum of a *large numbers* of *small quantities*.

Other Simple Difference can be-

The `Summation` is a `discrete sum` whereas `Integration` is a `continuous sum`.

Example:

[image]

> Here dx is an infinitesimal so that the integral summation is
> continuous.

Hope it helps, cheers! :)

Comment: Glad, I could help man. Update me if you need any other help. Cheers!

Comment: Abhishek bhai what if rather than using  1^2+ 2^2 +3^2...... What if i use 1^2+ 1.001^2+1.002^2+1.003^2..... Till n square... Wouldn't that be same... I mean discrete word is quite arbitrary in reality i could use this and will come close to result.. isn't it

Comment: Observe the 2nd difference closely. Actually, Integration can be interpreted as a special form of summation. In numerical computation methods, integration is always performed as a summation so we always need to be sure about it. Now coming to your query- Yes, you can but see as you said you'll be close to the result and that matters in the terms of accuracy. So It's better it use as per the computation and requirement.

Comment: Please answer this query as well

Comment: In practise summation is what we do while calculating integration of unknown equations but in theory or maths we take epsilon or dx an arbitory small number that approach to zero and derive an equation out of it. Am i interpreting it right

Comment: Yes, you're close. For more depth study on that, I'll recommend you to go through Andrew ng/Stanford course on coursera, that will help you to grasp the pith using practical approach and examples. Explore that.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort abhishek... But my takeaway is that integration is for driving a function out of a equation which tells the area under the cruve and is absolutely mathematical concept... Summation is a practical and statistical concept that gives an answer right away... Please do leave a closing comment